# Python3 bignum division

Tags: python-3.x, bignum

In python3, I divided big integer like 987654321987654321 by 100.
The result from python3 is 9876543219876544.0.

```
>>>987654321987654321/100
9876543219876544.0
```

However, if small number like 987654321 is divided by 100, the result is 9876543.21.

```
>>>987654321/100
9876543.21
```

I want to know why big number division does work like first version. Also, I want to know that I can get same result as the second version with big number.
Could help me, please?

Comment: My python3 version is 3.5.2

Comment: do you want a rounded result or an exact integer result?